# function to fill data into buffer with append everytime

Tags: c, embedded

I am in doubt how to fill data into a buffer append without using global variables.

```
int main(){
    char buffer[100];
    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
        write_to_buffer(buffer);
    }
}

void write_to_buffer(char* buffer){
    char* p = buffer;

    p += sprintf(p, "%f,", version);
}
```

Something like this would just overwrite the buffer everytime the function is called.
How can i use a pointer to keep track? or any other ideas for a good solution?

Comment: First of all, you don't need the temporary variable `p`, you can use `buffer` directly. Secondly, from the `main` function pass `buffer + strlen(buffer)` (if you initialize it first!)?

Comment: THis is not valid C. You have to declare a function before using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to start to fill the buffer from the current length.

```
int main(){
    char buffer[100] = ""; // start with an empty string, so strlen(buffer) returns 0
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        write_to_buffer(buffer);
    }
}

void write_to_buffer(char* buffer){
    sprintf(&buffer[strlen(buffer)], "%f,", version);
}
```

However, for embedded programming where cpu is not so fast, I would definitely pass buffer current and maximum length as parameters and return the number of appended characters:

```
int main() {
    char buffer[100];
    const size_t buffer_size = sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(buffer[0]);
    size_t buffer_pos = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        buffer_pos += write_to_buffer(&buffer[buffer_pos], buffer_size - buffer_pos);
    }
}

size_t write_to_buffer(char* buffer, size_t size){
    return snprintf(buffer, size, "%f,", version);
}
```

or with a pointer, however I prefer to represent a range with size_t, not with end pointer:

```
int main() {
    char buffer[100];
    char *pnt = buffer;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        pnt = write_to_buffer(pnt);
    }
    const size_t buffer_len = pnt - buffer;
}

char* write_to_buffer(char* buffer) {
    return buffer + sprintf(buffer, "%f,", version);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple and an effective way to do the job. Use static keyword like this

```
    int main(){
        char buffer[100];
        for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
        write_to_buffer(buffer);
        }
    }

    void write_to_buffer(char* buffer){
        static pos=0;
        char* p = &buffer[pos];
        sprintf(p, "%f,", version);
        pos+=1;
    }
```

Comment: Should be at least `char *p = &buffer[pos]` and `pos += sprintf(...`. Using static local function variables in such a way is a very bad idea.

Comment: Once used the function can't be used for another new string, since there's no way to reset `pos`. Also, implicit `int` is kind of old-fashioned.

Comment: Oh and not to mention that it will not work if the `version` number is more than one digit!

Comment: Yes, of course, it will not work for a number more than one digit, but I copied from the question to elaborate. All other comments are valid I agree. thanks.